# How to convert TData to TLSharp session?

Tags: c#, session, telegram, tlsharp

How to convert TData to TLSharp session ?

I got an hex authKey by python script from TData but i cant to create right session file for TLSharp. Can anybody share a code example ?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Before asking a question, you need to put forth some effort to solve the problem so you can post a code sample of what you have already tried.  The the community can provide some guidance.  See this link for more info on asking good questions - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. We can just replace an authkey of real session.dat TLSharp with authkey of tdata by sessionstore.It's enough for correct work.

Comment: Can you share the solution code?